# Pagination not working using ExtJS 4 and Java REST WS

Tags: java, javascript, grid, extjs4, paging

I finished with an application which requires getting data form a REST WS made in Java. The problem is that When I make the pagination in the client side (javascript) it is not working appropriately, I have 151 records that need to be shown in groups of 12. But When I look at the Web page, only the first 12 records are being showed and I can't go to next page or see the missing records.

Here I attach my Javascript code using ExtJS 4:

```
Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*']);

Ext.define('Pokemon', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {name : 'number', type : 'int'}, 'name', 'types' ]
});

Ext.onReady(function() {

//  Ext.Msg.alert("Welcome Message", "Welcome to first example");

    var proxy = new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest-extjs/rest/pokedata/list',
        model: 'Pokemon',
        reader: Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Json', {type: 'json', root: 'data', totalProperty: 'total'})
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 12,
        model: 'Pokemon',
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: proxy,
        sorters: [{
            property : 'number',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {text: "Number", width: 50, dataIndex: 'number'},
            {text: "Name", width: 130, dataIndex: 'name'},
            {text: "Types", width: 130, dataIndex: 'types'}
        ],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: store,
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true
        }],
        renderTo:'grid',
        width: 310,
        height: 380,
    });

    store.load({params: {start: 0, limit: 12}});

});
```

This is my REST Web Service:

```
package com.vz.samples.rest.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.vz.samples.data.response.JsonResponse;
import com.vz.samples.dto.PokemonDTO;
import com.vz.samples.reader.PokeDataReader;

@Path("/pokedata")
public class PokeDataRestService {

    final String filePath = "c:/dev/pokelist.txt";
    private PokeDataReader pdr = PokeDataReader.getInstance(filePath);

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public JsonResponse listAllPokemon(@QueryParam("start") int start, @QueryParam("limit") int limit) {
        JsonResponse jresp = null;      
        List<PokemonDTO> pokeList = null;       

        pokeList = pdr.readAllPokeData(start, limit);

        jresp = new JsonResponse();
        jresp.setId("pokedex");
        jresp.setData(pokeList);
        jresp.setMessage("Success");
        jresp.setTotal(pokeList.size());

        return jresp;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{number}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public JsonResponse getPokemonByNumber(@PathParam("number") int number) {
        JsonResponse jresp = null;
        PokemonDTO targetPokemon = null;

        targetPokemon = pdr.findByNumber(number);

        jresp = new JsonResponse();
        jresp.setId("pokemon");
        jresp.setData(targetPokemon);
        jresp.setMessage("Success");
        jresp.setTotal(1);

        return jresp;
    }



}
```

And finally this is the JSON I receive:

```
{"data":[{"name":"Bulbasaur","number":1,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"IvySaur","number":2,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Venasaur","number":3,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Charmander","number":4,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Charmeleon","number":5,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Charizard","number":6,"types":["Fire/Flying"]},{"name":"Squirtle","number":7,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Wartortle","number":8,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Blastoise","number":9,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Caterpie","number":10,"types":["Bug"]},{"name":"Metapod","number":11,"types":["Bug"]},{"name":"Butterfree","number":12,"types":["Bug/Flying"]},{"name":"Weedle","number":13,"types":["Bug/Poison"]},{"name":"Kakuna","number":14,"types":["Bug/Poison"]},{"name":"Beedrill","number":15,"types":["Bug/Poison/Flying"]},{"name":"Pidgey","number":16,"types":["Normal/Flying"]},{"name":"PÃ¯dgeotto","number":17,"types":["Normal/Flying"]},{"name":"Pidgeot","number":18,"types":["Normal/Flying"]},{"name":"Ratatta","number":19,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Raticate","number":20,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Spearow","number":21,"types":["Normal/Flying"]},{"name":"Fearow","number":22,"types":["Normal/Flying"]},{"name":"Ekans","number":23,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Arbok","number":24,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Pikachu","number":25,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Raichu","number":26,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Sandshrew","number":27,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Sandslash","number":28,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Nidoran Female","number":29,"types":["Normal/Poison"]},{"name":"Nidorina","number":30,"types":["Normal/Poison"]},{"name":"Nidoqueen","number":31,"types":["Ground/Poison"]},{"name":"Nidoran Male","number":32,"types":["Normal/Poison"]},{"name":"Nidorino","number":33,"types":["Normal/Poison"]},{"name":"Nidoking","number":34,"types":["Ground/Poison"]},{"name":"Cleafairy","number":35,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Cleafable","number":36,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Vulpix","number":37,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Ninetales","number":38,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Jigglypuff","number":39,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Wigglytuff","number":40,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Zubat","number":41,"types":["Poison/Flying"]},{"name":"Golbat","number":42,"types":["Poison/Flying"]},{"name":"Oddish","number":43,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Gloom","number":44,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Vileplume","number":45,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Paras","number":46,"types":["Grass/Bug"]},{"name":"Parasect","number":47,"types":["Grass/Bug"]},{"name":"Venonat","number":48,"types":["Bug/Psychic"]},{"name":"Venomoth","number":49,"types":["Bug/Psychic"]},{"name":"Digglet","number":50,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Dugtrio","number":51,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Meowth","number":52,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Persian","number":53,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Psyduck","number":54,"types":["Water/Psychic"]},{"name":"Golduck","number":55,"types":["Water/Psychic"]},{"name":"Mankey","number":56,"types":["Fightining"]},{"name":"Primeape","number":57,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Growlithe","number":58,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Arcanine","number":59,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Poliwag","number":60,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Poliwhirl","number":61,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Poliwrath","number":62,"types":["Water/Fight"]},{"name":"Abra","number":63,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Kadabra","number":64,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Alakazam","number":65,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Machop","number":66,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Machoke","number":67,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Machamp","number":68,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Bellsprout","number":69,"types":["Grass"]},{"name":"Weepinbell","number":70,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Victribel","number":71,"types":["Grass/Poison"]},{"name":"Tentacool","number":72,"types":["Water/Poison"]},{"name":"Tentacruel","number":73,"types":["Water/Poison"]},{"name":"Geodude","number":74,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Graveler","number":75,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Golem","number":76,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Ponyta","number":77,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Rapidash","number":78,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Slowpoke","number":79,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Slowbro","number":80,"types":["Water/Psychic"]},{"name":"Magnemite","number":81,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Magneton","number":82,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Farfetch'd","number":83,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Doduo","number":84,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Dodrio","number":85,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Seel","number":86,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Dewgong","number":87,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Grimer","number":88,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Muk","number":89,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Shellder","number":90,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Cloyster","number":91,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Gastly","number":92,"types":["Ghost"]},{"name":"Haunter","number":93,"types":["Ghost"]},{"name":"Gengar","number":94,"types":["Ghost"]},{"name":"Onix","number":95,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Drowzee","number":96,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Hypno","number":97,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Krabby","number":98,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Kingler","number":99,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Voltorb","number":100,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Electrode","number":101,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Exeggcute","number":102,"types":["Grass/Psychic"]},{"name":"Exeggutor","number":103,"types":["Grass/Psychic"]},{"name":"Cubone","number":104,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Marowak","number":105,"types":["Ground"]},{"name":"Hitmonlee","number":106,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Hitmonchan","number":107,"types":["Fight"]},{"name":"Lickitung","number":108,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Koffing","number":109,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Weezing","number":110,"types":["Poison"]},{"name":"Rhyhorn","number":111,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Rhydon","number":112,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Chansey","number":113,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Tangela","number":114,"types":["Grass"]},{"name":"Kanghskhan","number":115,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Horsea","number":116,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Seadra","number":117,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Goldeen","number":118,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Seaking","number":119,"types":["Waters"]},{"name":"Staryu","number":120,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Starmie","number":121,"types":["Water/Psychic"]},{"name":"Mr.Mime","number":122,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Scyther","number":123,"types":["Bug"]},{"name":"Jinx","number":124,"types":["Ice"]},{"name":"Electabuzz","number":125,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Magmar","number":126,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Pinsir","number":127,"types":["Bug"]},{"name":"Tauros","number":128,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Magikarp","number":129,"types":["Water"]},{"name":"Gyarados","number":130,"types":["Water/Flying"]},{"name":"Lapras","number":131,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Ditto","number":132,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Eevee","number":133,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Vaporeon","number":134,"types":["Water/Ice"]},{"name":"Jolteon","number":135,"types":["Electric"]},{"name":"Flareon","number":136,"types":["Fire"]},{"name":"Porygon","number":137,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Omanyte","number":138,"types":["Water/Rock"]},{"name":"Omastar","number":139,"types":["Water/Rock"]},{"name":"Kabuto","number":140,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Kabutops","number":141,"types":["Rock"]},{"name":"Aerodactyl","number":142,"types":["Rock/Flying"]},{"name":"Snorlax","number":143,"types":["Normal"]},{"name":"Articuno","number":144,"types":["Ice/Flying"]},{"name":"Zapdos","number":145,"types":["Electric/Flying"]},{"name":"Moltres","number":146,"types":["Fire/Flying"]},{"name":"Dratini","number":147,"types":["Dragon"]},{"name":"Dragonair","number":148,"types":["Dragon"]},{"name":"Dragonite","number":149,"types":["Dragon/Flying"]},{"name":"Mewtwo","number":150,"types":["Psychic"]},{"name":"Mew","number":151,"types":["Psychic"]}],"id":"pokedex","message":"Success","total":151}
```

Do I need to include an additional parameter or maybe JS component to make it work?

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is almost certainly in your server-side code. Ext JS does absolutely nothing in the way of restricting which records are or are not shown for a remotely configured store. All that Ext JS does it submit an AJAX request, with particular parameters, and waits for the response. When it receives the response, it tries to handle it and, if that's successful, renders the data from your model instances into your grid. In this sense, Ext JS's relationship to the paging data is really that of a handshake--a request and expectation to receive data in a certain format.

The important part of this, then, is that Ext JS is wholly dependent upon the data from your server being returned correctly in order to handle pagination. If the records in the grid aren't correct, you need to first check the data coming back from the server. More than likely, what you're seeing in your grid is *precisely* what your server is sending back for Ext JS to show.

My guess is the issue is in your `readAllPokeData()` method. I'd start there and make sure it's actually paging the data on the server side. If that's not working correctly, Ext JS will be unable to do anything but render out the data that the server gives it.